# Map into a list of pairs

Tags: ocaml

Can you help me please in order to create a function that takes 2 arguments: a map of strings and a function that transform a string in another one(like `string.uppercase`) and returns a list of pairs formed of the map’s key and the value transformed by the string function.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You'll get a better response if you first try to solve the problem yourself and then let us know which part you're struggling with by posting your code.

Comment: Could you, at least, provide a function signature?

Comment: see https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/ocaml/

Comment: What is the representation of the map of strings? Is it a hash map? Is it an association list? This will help.  Even providing some pseudo code can help people get a clear sense of what you're trying to do and what you already understand.

Comment: I have two guesses as to the function signature: 1. `'a Map.Make(String).t -> (string -> string) -> (string * 'a) list`, 2. `string Map.Make(X).t -> (string -> string) -> (X.t * string) list` but it isn’t clear to me whether the author would want this function to be polymorphic in the type of the key.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `Map` module from the standard library to generate your map, it already conveniently provides `map` and `bindings` methods.

We can easily create a string to string map module and then our own functor that lets this problem be mapped to *any* type of map, then specialize it for our `String_map` module.

```
module String_map = Map.Make (String)

module Homework_functor (M : Map.S) =
struct
  let map_and_get_bindings f m =
    m |> M.map f
      |> M.bindings
end

module Homework = Homework_functor (String_map)
```

```
utop # String_map.(
  empty |> add "foo" "bar"
        |> add "hello" "world"
) |>
Homework.map_and_get_bindings String.uppercase_ascii;;
- : (string * string) list = [("foo", "BAR"); ("hello", "WORLD")]
```

Or as a second example:

```
utop # String_map.(
  empty |> add "foo" "bar"
        |> add "hello" "world"
) |>
Homework.map_and_get_bindings @@ fun s -> s.[0];;
- : (string * char) list = [("foo", 'b'); ("hello", 'w')]
```